# Salvar dados servidor IP

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Pessoal bom dia ao tentar conectar a um servidor configurei o meu firewall e configurei os arquivos pg.conf e pg_hb.conf para permitir conexões remotas mas apresenta esse erro poderiam me ajudar ?

ele apresenta o seguinte erro

O servidor não aceita conexões: os relatórios da biblioteca de conexões
Não pôde se conectar ao servidor: A conexão expirou (0x0000274C / 10060) O servidor está sendo executado no host "192.168.1.251" e aceitando conexões TCP / IP na porta 5432?

Comment: O SO do teu servidor é Windows? A Aplicação chega a conectar no banco de dados em algum momento? Como fez a liberação do Firewall?

Comment: Laércio mei sistema operacional é windows no caso no momento ele está conectando normalmente em uma conexão localhost, mas quero salvar os dados em um servidor com ip 192.168.1.251.Eu configurei meu firewall assim                                                                                         Painel de controle, permitir programa ou recurso firewall, postgreSQL marquei a opção domestica, Público.

Comment: É exatamente da mesma forma que eu costumo configurar e funciona corretamente. Você configurou o postgre na porta 5432 mesmo?

Comment: sim, a porta padrão do postreSql 5432

Comment: no caso eu teria que configurar meu servidor ?

Comment: Como você configurou seu `pg.config` e o `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Pessoal eu conversando com um amigo meu eu preciso liberar a porta 5432 do firewall do servidor e do roteador ai sim vai resolver meu roblema

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal

Comment: Resolveu o problema? Se não, coloca o como está o pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Resolvi man, configurei o firewal pra permiti a a entrada d aporta 5432 e configurei o hb.conf com o ip do servivor